# Swift 3 Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'object'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have updated swift 3 and I found many errors. This is one of them :

> Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'object'

This is my code :

```
jsonmanager.post( "http://myapi.com",
                      parameters: nil,
                      success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?,responseObject: Any?) in
                        if(((responseObject? as AnyObject).object(forKey: "meta") as AnyObject).object(forKey: "status")?.intValue == 200 && responseObject?.object(forKey: "total_data")?.intValue > 0){
                            let aa: Any? = (responseObject? as AnyObject).object(forKey: "response")

                            self.data = (aa as AnyObject).mutableCopy() 
                        }
```

New Error Update :

> Optional chain has no effect, expression already produces 'Any?'

And

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'Any?!'

It works well in previous version 7.3.1 swift 2.

This is json response :

```
{
 "meta":{"status":200,"msg":"OK"},
        "response":[""],
        "total_data":0
}
```

Comment: Please show us your json response?

Comment: see updated question @NiravD

Comment: I have told you to show us your json response, so that we can create dictionary on the basis of that.

Comment: What type is `jsonmanager`?

Comment: @kabiroberai AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Comment: @Nirav D sorry, see again

Comment: There is no key with `total_data` in your response?

Comment: @NiravD I missed it :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unlike Swift 2, Swift 3 imports Objective-C's `id` as `Any?` instead of `AnyObject?` (see [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0116-id-as-any.md) Swift evolution proposal). To fix your error, you need to cast all of your variables to `AnyObject`. This may look something like the following:

```
jsonmanager.post("http://myapi.com", parameters: nil) { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?, responseObject: Any?) in
    let response = responseObject as AnyObject?
    let meta = response?.object(forKey: "meta") as AnyObject?
    let status = meta?.object(forKey: "status") as AnyObject?
    let totalData = response?.object(forKey: "total_data") as AnyObject?
    if status?.intValue == 200 && totalData?.intValue != 0 {
        let aa = response?.object(forKey: "response") as AnyObject?
        self.data = aa?.mutableCopy() 
    }
}
```

Comment: after i change, i got the first error : Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'object'

Comment: @stevengbu can you show me your updated code? Make sure that you are accessing `response` instead of `responseObject`

Comment: @stevengbu I just edited my answer, you may want to try with the new code

Comment: @stevengbu nevermind, I spotted the issue (and updated the answer once more). Try again.

Answer (score 1):

Your `responseObject` is `Optional` (specifically, an `Any?`), so you have to unwrap it in order to call its methods or access its properties, like `responseObject?.object(forKey: "meta")`, etc. There are several places in the frameworks where values that used to be non-`Optional` are now `Optional`, especially where they were used in Objective-C without a specified nullability qualifier.