# how to access Array with key in swift4

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am very new to swift, I used to code in objective C, but Now I am facing alot of problems while development in Swift. Right now I have json file imported in project

```
let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "json")

do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: file!)

    //let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

    let json:NSArray = try (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSArray)!


    print(json[0])

} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

It gives output like

```
{
Correct = 1;
    EA = "50 Days  ";
    EB = "40 days";
    EC = "90 days";
    ED = "30  days";
}
```

And i Need to access only Content with key "EA".

previously with objective C, I used to access it like

```
[[json objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"EA"]
```

Now when I am trying to access it like

```
json[0].objectForKey("EA") as? String
```

it says

> Value of type 'Any' has no member 'objectForKey'

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502476/swift-3-value-of-type-any-has-no-member-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 2**

```
(json[0] as! NSDictionary).objectForKey("EA") as? String
```

**Swift 3 & 4**

```
(json[0] as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "EA") as? String
```

Comment: wow, thanks it worked 

but after silencing some warnings it looked like this



`print((json[0] as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "EA") as? Int as Any)`

Comment: Yeah sorry. That was Swift 2 syntax. I work with different projects written in different versions of swift and I tend to lose track of which syntax belongs to which. I'll update the answer